Select coloured text in terminal-normal mode
Vim's :terminal buffers are incredibly useful. Sometimes, I run a command which produces coloured output, which highlights important information.
Is there a regex or some other method that I can use to select such text when I enter terminal-normal mode (i.e. C-w N)?
I know that when I perform actions such as yank, no text escape sequences are yanked, so perhaps the colour information is not in-band selectable by regex, but it seems conceivable that some way exists, as the coloured text produced by the terminal remain coloured as I enter the terminal-normal mode.

Ok, term_scrape() seems to provide the necessary information and I can mash the coloured text into a regex using the vim "ordinary-atom"s /\%l and /\%c. Let me cook something up.
